# multiple textboxex and insert query in angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, sql-server

I am creating a web app in  which i need to enter location and areas

as of now i want 10 textboxes with `ng-model="area"`

```
@{
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            <p><input type="text" ng-model="area" /></p>
        }
    }
```

i used for loop for using multiple textbox for same ng-model name, but when i enter a text in single textbox the text is being showin in all textbox [image]
I want to use it like the following[image]

and then i want to insert the same from webservice with the help of angularjs

here are the examples about how normaly use insert query

Angularjs Controller

```
$scope.updatefunction = function (param) {
            $scope.updateparam = param;
            console.log($scope.updateparam.comarea);

            $http.get('/allotcompany.asmx/insertarea', {
                params: {
                    comname: $scope.mdcomname,
                    brandname: $scope.mdbrandname,
                    zone: $scope.mdzone,
                    location: $scope.location,
                    area: $scope.updateparam.comarea
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                alert(response.data.info);
                $scope.gettableinfo();
            });
        }
```

and web service for the same

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public void insertarea(string comname, string brandname, string zone, string location, string area)
        {
            string id = "";
            var json = "";
            SqlCommand cmdcom = new SqlCommand("select id from companydetails where comname='" + comname + "'", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader drcom = cmdcom.ExecuteReader();
            while (drcom.Read())
            {
                id = drcom["id"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
            List<object> addarea = new List<object>();
            if (brandname != "select")
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into companyallot values('" + id + "','" + location + "','" + area + "','" + zone + "','" + brandname + "',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                json = js.Serialize("Area Added with brandname");
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into companyallot values('" + id + "','" + location + "','" + area + "','" + zone + "',Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null)", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                json = js.Serialize("Area Added For All Brands");
                con.Close();
            }
            Context.Response.Write("{" + '"' + "info" + '"' + ":" + json + "}");
        }
```

these are simple insert query now i want insert query which will insert many records at once depending upon the user

Comment: Don't mix the razor and AngularJS. You should use ng-repeat to create dynamic textbox.
Check more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113165/adding-a-textbox-element-dynamically-to-a-form-by-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <p><input type="text" ng-model="area @i" /></p>
    }
}
```

this is how I did this and in angular-Controller I used loop to get all the city name